# Read CSV and store in Pandas and convert the specific column into int

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns in csv and read the csv and store it in pandas df. Once the data stored in df, it becomes object. I wanted to convert the "A" column into int. Eg. below:

A  B
1  2
1  3
3  4
4  5

```
file_path  = "C:\\a.csv"
data       =  pd.read_csv(file_path,names['A','B'],encoding='latin1', skiprows=[0])
df         = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.dtypes)
```

df.dtypes print the dtype as Object. Now i wanted to convert this object to int64.
I am unable to do it.

Things Tried:

```
df['A']    = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors="coerce") #converted to float64
df['A']    = df['A'].fillna('')
df['A']    = df['A'].astype('int64')
df['A']    = df['A'].astype('str').astype('int64')
```

None of them converted to int64. As i need this column as int so i need to use this to compare other columns. Appreciate your help.

Comment: please show a result of: df['A'].unique()

Comment: [' 001 ' '-' ' 004 ' ' 003 ' ' 002 ' ':001 ' ' 401(' '~004~' ' 005 '
 ' 001\n' ' 009 ' '(001,' '~014 ']

Comment: After doing this -  df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(r'\D', '')                                                      ['001' '' '004' '003' '002' '401' '005' '009' '014']

Answer (score 0):

As much as this is ugly, it works:

```
np.floor(pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')).astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

Comment: Mine is a big dataframe contains 500 rows. How this series will work? Should i give all the values ? whats this 'sa' mean ?

Comment: this is an example series:
pd.Series([1.2, 1, 'sa']). 500 rows is pretty small for a df.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to do this.

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors="coerce").fillna(0).astype(int).to_frame()
```

The above code does not round to integers. If you want the numbers to be rounded up, you can give this. The `.round()` after `fillna(0)` and `.astype(int)` will round upwards. That's an option for you if you are looking for values to be rounded up to the integer.

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors="coerce").fillna(0).round().astype(int).to_frame()
```

It will convert the `NaN` values to `0` and then convert everything to integer values. That way you will get the desired values.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1.8, 3.3, 5.2, 'Good', 7, 9,2],
                   'B':['Apple','Banana','Cherry','Donuts','Egg','Fig','Grape']})
print (df)
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors="coerce").fillna(0).astype(int).to_frame()
print (df)
```

This will convert the values in `df['A']` to numeric while also setting all strings to `NaN`, then converting those `NaN`s to `0` then converting all of it to int. Since this is a Series, you need to convert it back to a dataframe with the `to_frame()`

The output for the above code is:

Original DataFrame:

```
      A       B
0   1.8   Apple
1   3.3  Banana
2   5.2  Cherry
3  Good  Donuts
4     7     Egg
5     9     Fig
6     2   Grape
```

Converted DataFrame:

```
   A       B
0  1   Apple
1  3  Banana
2  5  Cherry
3  0  Donuts
4  7     Egg
5  9     Fig
6  2   Grape
```

Comment: df_bot['extracted_value'] = pd.to_numeric(df_bot['extracted_value'],errors="coerce").fillna('').astype(int).to_frame()                                                                      I tried the above code but throwing an error:                                                                                                                                            
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: You have to do fillna(0.0) not fillna(''). Otherwise it is trying to convert '' to int

Comment: Yes i tried that and it worked. I am using this int64 column along with one more int64 column and passing to sequenceMatcher  function to compare two columns and return the ratio.  I am getting the below error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable                 
  def similiarity_ratio(df_merge,col1,col2):
             return SequenceMatcher(None, df_merge[col1],df_merge[col2]).ratio()                    Things i tried:                                       Converted back to objects from int64 to object but still same error.  df_merge['PC_Value'] = df_merge['PC_Value'].astype('object')

Comment: Can you please let me know what's the scope of work and what's the desired results. Unable to understand  your problem statement.